# How to find the smallest $n$ such that $n^a\equiv 1 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given a prime $p$ and number $a$, how do I find the smallest $n$ such that $n^a\equiv 1 \pmod p$? Is there a non trial-and-error method?

Edit: obviously removing $n=1$!

Comment: $n=1$ works for all and it's the smallest

Comment: I've edited your notation since $\mod{ }$ when used without equivalence signs is an operation and trivially $1\mod p = 1$ so that you're asking for the lowest $n$ s.t. $n^a=1$, which of course is not what you want.

Comment: Do you mean $\,a^n\,$ vs. $\,n^a?\ \ $

Comment: No. I am not talking about the order. I mean what I said for $n$ not $1$.

Comment: Sometimes $n=1$ is the only answer, such as when $p=5$ and $a=3$.

Answer (score 2):

The [Tonelli-Shanks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) and [Cipolla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla's_algorithm) algorithms  for square-roots can easily be generalized to compute d'th roots in finite fields, e.g. see  Adleman; Manders; Miller: [On taking roots in finite fields](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/AMM77.pdf), and Bach; Shallit: [Algorithmic number theory, section 7.3.](http://books.google.com/books?id=iJx1lP9ZcIkC&pg=PA160)  See also [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1181312/242)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet found an example where $n \not\equiv 1$, $a=3$, and $\gcd(p-1,3) = 1$.  So I suspect nontrivial answers only exist when $\gcd(p-1,3) \ne 1$.

When $\gcd(a,p-1) = k \ne 1$, we have $\forall n \not\equiv 0, n^{\frac{a(p-1)}{k}} = \left(n^{\frac{a}{k}}\right)^{p-1} \equiv 1$, so $\forall n \not\equiv 0, \left(n^{\frac{p-1}{k}}\right)^a \equiv 1$.

This suggests an algorithm where you search for the smallest $\frac{p-1}{k}$th power, but I'm not sure how you'd go about that.

Comment: Note that for $p>3$, $p$ has the form $6m\pm 1 \Rightarrow p-1=6m,6m-2$. gcd$(p-1,3)\ne 1 \Rightarrow p=6m+1$