# Find all the $16^{th}$ roots of $2 \bmod 178481$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Find all the $16^{th}$ roots of $2 \bmod 178481$.

I tried to solve it by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: You should consider renaming the question to something relevant. Also, please try to include your work/attempts to attract more answers.

Comment: @Woodface I (wrongly) thought that we should refrain to make drastic changes to the title. At least that is what I have observed... People refrain from $L^AT_EX$-ing the questions' titles, et cetera.

Answer (score 3):

Extended hints/steps:

1. Prove that $p=178481$ is a prime.
2. Factor $p-1=2^4p_1p_2p_3$, where $p_1<p_2<p_3$ are three distinct odd primes.
3. Check that $2^{p_2}\equiv1\pmod p$. Why does this prove that $2$ is a sixteenth power modulo $p$? Why does this, together with step 2, prove that there are sixteen distinct solutions.
4. Show that $9p_2+1=16k$ for some integer $k$.
5. Why does that show that $x=2^k$ satisfies the congruence $x^{16}\equiv2\pmod p$?
6. Find a primitive sixteenth root of unity $w$ modulo $p$. Hint: for any integer $a, \gcd(a,p)=1$, we have that $a^{p_1p_2p_3}$ is a sixteenth root of unity modulo $p$. The catch is to find a primitive one by testing various values of $a$. In the interest of not being too cruel I will tell you that a choice $a, 0<a<5$, will work.
7. Show that all the pairwise non-congruent solutions are $xw^i$, $i=0,1,\ldots,15$.

I hope you can use a CAS. Otherwise you are gonna have a long night. Step six in particular may be time consuming - the others are relatively quick to do. Unless you come up with something more clever that is.

Answer (score 1):

$p = 178481\,$ is prime. $ $ mod $\,p\!:\ 2$ has order dividing $\,p\!-\!1 = 16\cdot 11155.$ By CAS $\,2^{11155}\equiv 1.\,$ By Bezout, ${\rm mod}\ 11155\!:\ 1/16 \equiv 3486.\,$ Thus $\ {\rm mod}\ p\!:\ 2^{1/16}\equiv 2^{3486}\equiv 8192\equiv 2^{13}$

Thus the $16$'th roots of $\,2\,$ are $2^{13} w^k\,$ for a primitive $16$th root of unity $w$. Find one by randomly searching for a nonsquare $\,a\,$ (i.e. $\,a^{(p-1)/2}\not\equiv 1),\,$ then computing $\,w = a^{11155}$

**Remark** $\ $ Above we exploited the fact that it is easy to compute $k$'th roots in groups whose order is coprime to $k$.  More generally one may apply generalizations of the [Shanks or Tonelli square-root algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm), e.g. see Section 3.2: Extensions of Shanks's algorithm to r'th roots in cyclic groups in Lindhurst: [Computing roots in finite fields and groups, with a jaunt through sums of digits](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.144.2770&rep=rep1&type=pdf). One can also generalize the Euler criterion for square-roots - see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5424/how-can-i-find-out-whether-a-number-is-a-quadratic-residue-in-a-large-modulo/5433#5433) and Chapter 4 of Ireland and Rosen, *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory.*

Comment: In fact $\,2^{23}\equiv 1\,$ but that doesn't really speed things up much since the CAS calculations are rapid either way.