# Is it possible to calculate x having all other information in ((x^3)+5) mod p where p is a known large prime?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Please kindly note that I am a beginner. My questions are these:

Is it possible to calculate `x` from the following data? If yes, how? If not, why not?

```
((x^3)+5) mod  111267492025176636775873676207109540284671533365944463094334269908178130251703 = 77728417551815895917893167053908013392240543644078528175107278902132954431973
```

I am using SageMath with these large numbers.

I was told that my problem involves the Discrete log problem but I don't think so. The DL problem seems to have the form: `find y from n = x^y (mod p)`. In my case, we know `n`, `y` and `p`. We need to find `x`.

Thanks!

Comment: all you know is $x^3+5\pmod p$ for some large $p$?  Then, of course you can't compute $x$ as an integer.  It is only determined $\pmod p$ at best and possibly even that is not unique.  Or were you asking something else?

Comment: Side note:  for your large prime  $p$ we have $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  That means that there are non-trivial solutions to $a^3\equiv 1 \pmod p$ so $x$, if it exists, is not even unique $\mod p$.

Comment: I have the x. It is 22692086242441054492793625613426305119234074335268066503292205729740440378019. I want to know if it can be calculated. So I guess it is not possible.

Comment: The [Tonelli-Shanks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) and [Cipolla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla's_algorithm) algorithms  for square-roots can easily be generalized to compute d'th roots in finite fields, e.g. see  Adleman; Manders; Miller: [On taking roots in finite fields](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/AMM77.pdf), and Bach; Shallit: [Algorithmic number theory, section 7.3.](http://books.google.com/books?id=iJx1lP9ZcIkC&pg=PA160)  See also [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1181312/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PARI/GP , you can find the three possible values.

Set $$c=77728417551815895917893167053908013392240543644078528175107278902132954431973$$
    $$p=111267492025176636775873676207109540284671533365944463094334269908178130251703$$

Then, the command "lift(factormod(x^3+5-c,p))" gives this output :

```
? lift(factormod(x^3+5-c,p))
%53 =
[x + 602682757193745542178710070302898494458432132023749413582805581887225347898
47 1]

[x + 736913025482431370507962947902459959580623944988375882393459174491960358398
75 1]

[x + 885754057827355822830800505936832351654374590306763965910420641784376898736
84 1]
```

Subtracting those numbers from $p$ gives you the $3$ possible values, one of those is the one you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. I have installed PARI/GP and this works. Thank you for your help!