# Could we find an element on finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, computational-mathematics, computational-algebra

Let $F$ be a finite field.
Given an element $a^x$ in $F\setminus\{0\}$, could we find $a$??
I know that finding an integer $x$ is very hard problem (Discrete Logarithm Problem). However, I don't know the hardness of this problem.
What's the problem's name?
Thanks.

Comment: What is $x$? Is it a natural number? And is it given or not?

Comment: sorry, I have many mistakes. x is also given and x is natural number

Comment: Do you know that $F\backslash\{0\}$ is a cyclic group?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177537

Comment: @Servaes Yeah, I studied abstract algebra

Comment: @Watson Why this link is related my question? I think they are different.

Comment: @swain : it is related when your finite field is $\Bbb F_p$, and when $x=2$, because the answer links to the Cipolla's and Tonelli-Shanks' algorithms, which are part of the computational number theory (related to your tags).

Answer (score 1):

Let $q = |F|$. Since $(F^*,\times)$ is a cyclic group of order $q-1$, you are basically asking when and how we can divide by $x$ in $\Bbb Z/(q-1)\Bbb Z$.

This depends heavily on $x$. If $x$ and $q-1$ are not coprime, then this is impossible (for example if $x=q-1$ well $a^x= 1$ forall $a \in F^*$ so knowing $a^x$ gives you absolutely no information on $a$).

If they are, then $x$ has an inverse $y$ modulo $q-1$, and dividing by $x$ is the same as multiplying by $y$ : in the context of $(F^*,\times)$ this means that $a = (a^x)^y$.

Comment: Thanks. If x divide q-1 but not q-1, is the case also impossible?? I don't know the reason why this case is impossible

Comment: yes, if $xy = q-1$ then $xy = 0 = x0$ modulo $q-1$ so multiplication by $x$ is not injective and so it's not invertible ( multiplication by $x$ is then $x$-to-$1$)

Answer (score 0):

$0^x$ is in the field for every non-zero $x$.

Comment: Oh sorry, a^x in F-{0}