# How can I calculate $x=y^{\frac{1}z} \pmod n$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> How can I calculate $$x=y^{\frac{1}z} \pmod n$$

I have $y, z$ and $n$, but I really don't have any good ideas on how to get x without brute-forcing it. Is there any good way to calculate it?

Comment: [See here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1177599/242)

Comment: Given that the strength of the still very-much-in-use RSA algorithm for encryption is based on this problem being hard to solve, I wouldn't expect this problem to be easy to solve. I would, however, expect there to be a lot of work done on this subject. Little of which I'm familiar with.