# Congruence related to quadratic equation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Find the number of solutions of the congruence equation

$y^2 = 3x^2-x-9$ (mod $109$)

My progress: Considering myself as a beginner to these type of complex problems in Number Theory, I wonder if there is non-brute force way to find the number of solutions of this congruence. Taking granted, my knowledge in such quadratic equations is pretty low, so any suggestion or related theorems/lemmas/methods would be welcomed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you  want to try something similar to completing squares. So some knowledge of quadratic residues/ reciprocity is helpful. In this case, observe that $p=109$ is prime and we can write
\begin{align*}
y^2 & = 3x^2-x-9 \pmod{109}\\
&=3x^2-x+\color{red}{100} \pmod{109}\\
&=\color{red}{(60)^2}x-x+100 \pmod{109}\\
y^2&=(60)^2x-\color{red}{1200}x+(10)^2 \pmod{109}\\
y^2&=(60x-10)^2 \pmod{109}.
\end{align*}
Using the prime property ($p | ab \implies p|a \text{ or } p|b$) we get
$$y-60x+10 \equiv 0 \pmod{109} \text{ or } y+60x-10 \equiv 0 \pmod{109}.$$
Now you can count the solutions.

Comment: Very nice solution indeed. I did other manipulations, but none of them worked so beautiful as yours.

Comment: @DarkKnight Thanks!!

Comment: I think you meant $109$ where you typed $103 $ a couple places

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh yes!!, thanks for pointing it out. I will fix it.

Comment: @DarkKnight Except $\ \sqrt{3} \equiv \pm60\,$ was pulled out of a hat like magic. I show how to avoid any magic in my answer.

Comment: @Gone In the preface, I  have given the background of what is needed so one can say that I did not show all the steps but it is far from labeling it "magic".

Comment: @AnuragA  My point is that you don't say how you solved $\,a^2\equiv 3\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv \pm60.\,$ Rather, you pull the square root $\,60\,$ out of a hat, like magic. But magic is not math. Nothing in the "preface" explains how to compute that square root (it cannot be done merely by reciprocity)

Comment: @Gone I was referring to the phrase "completion of squares" and that is what exactly you have beautifully illustrated in your solution.

Comment: Ok, in case it wasn't clear my point was to hope to coax you into explaining how you found that square root since it might be instructive to readers. But maybe you found it by  computer so there is no further insight along that path. Generally there are [algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1177599/242), even though we don't need them here.

Comment: @Gone In fact, I just ensured that $3$ is QR mod $109$ (reciprocity) and then proceeded exactly the way you did in your solution $2ab=...$. The reason I chose not to put the details was just to nudge OP to think about how to find it (or ask for further explanation). My intent was more pedagogical (self-discovery) and not to make math appear like magic :-)

Comment: @AnuragA It's better to be much more explicit. It's impossible from what little is written above to have any clue at all what method was used (or even that there exists some method better than computing the square root).

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $109$ is prime. So, you want to know when $3x^2-x-9$ is quadratic residue mod $109$. There is a whole theory about quadratic residues mod $p$ prime (look for Legendre symbol).

For this particular problem, we first try to complete the square, we multiply the equation by 12 to try to complete squares in the right hand side (since 12 is coprime with 109, this equation is equivalent to the original one). We get:
$$12y^2=36x^2-12x-108 \pmod{109}$$
Luckily, the right hand side is in fact a perfect square mod 109,

$$12y^2=36x^2-12x+1=(6x-1)^2\pmod{109}$$
So, you have $$3(2y)^2=(6x-1)^2\pmod{109}$$
If $y=0\mod 109$, then $6x-1=0\bmod 109$, so you get one solution $(x,y)=(91,0)\pmod{109}$

If $y\neq 0\bmod 109$, then that would imply that $3= [(6x-1)(2y)^{-1}]^2\bmod 109$, i.e. $3$ would be a quadratic residue mod $109$.
 Is this possible? Let's see, by quadratic reciprocity, we have
$$\left(\frac{3}{109}\right)=\left(\frac{109}{3}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=1.$$
So, yes, 3 is a quadratic residue mod $109$. You will have two square roots of $3\pmod{109}$, say $a$ and $-a$.

So, you have $ (6x-1)(2y)^{-1}=a\pmod{109}$, which will give you 108 solutions (for each value of $y$, you have a unique value of $x$.
And similarly $ (6x-1)(2y)^{-1}=-a\pmod{109}$, gives you another 108 solutions.

In total, you will get $1+108+108=217$ solutions $(x,y)$ mod $109$.

**Edit**

1)Whenever you want to complete squares an expression like this $S=mx^2+nx$ with $m,n$ integer. Multiply the expression by $4m$ (in fact you only need to multiply it by $m$ if $n$ is even). Because in that way, you would have 
$$4mS=4m^2x^2+4mnx=(2mx+n)^2-n^2$$.
That's why in the problem we multiply the equation by $4(3)=12$, to make the completion of squares.

2) Note in this solution I never needed to compute a square root mod 109. Although,  something to point out, that I already mentioned, is that we really really got lucky to have a perfect square on the right hand side. If this wasn't the case, say instead we got $3(2y)^2=(6x-1)^2+2\pmod{109}$, then this would be painful since we would need to find two quadratic residues ($3(2y)^2$ and $(6x-1)^2$ ) whose difference is $2$. And I don't really see a way to count the solutions in an easy way.

Comment: But you pulled the crucial scale factor $12$ out of a hat, like magic. Such magic won't work in general. See my answer for one way to avoid any magic.

Comment: It's not magical at all. As I said, I just wanted to complete squares, the issue is that you need integers. You have $3x^2-x-9$. First you want to make the quadratic part an square, so technically you could have done it just by multiplying by $3$ (instead of 12), so you could  have $9x^2-3x-27$. The "issue" is that now this becomes $(3x-1/2)^2-27-1/4$. This still makes sense since 2 is invertible mod 109, but I just wanted to express everything with integer coefficients, so that's why I multiplied everything by 4. (So in total I multiply by a factor of 12).

Comment: In other words, I just tried to multiply the equation so that something as $a^2x^2+2ab x$ appears. (which is what appears from expanding $(ax+b)^2$ as in your solution.) In general if I had $mx^2+nx$ in one side of the equation, I would have multiplied it by $4m$, so that I get $4m^2x^2+4mnx=(2mx+n)^2-n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Without any *magic:* $\bmod 109\!:\ 3x^2\color{#c00}{-1}\,x\,\overbrace{-\,9}^{\large\color{#0a0}{ 10^2}} \equiv (ax+b)^2 \equiv a^2\, x+ \color{#c00}{2ab}\,x+\color{#0a0}{b^2}$

yields  $\,\color{#0a0}{b^2\! \equiv 10^2},\,$ wlog $\,b\!\equiv\!10,\,$ so $\,  \color{#c00}{2ab \equiv -1}\,$ $\Rightarrow\, 20b\equiv108\!\iff\! b \equiv \dfrac{27}5\equiv \dfrac{27\cdot 22}{110}\equiv \dfrac{49}1$

Further $\,a^2\equiv49^2\equiv 3\ $ so $\,a \equiv 49,\, b\equiv 10\,$ works. The rest is straightforward.

Comment: We computed the fraction by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) $\ \ $

Comment: or you could have said $20b\equiv108\iff5b\equiv27\equiv136\equiv245\iff b\equiv49$

Comment: @J.W.T Yes, that essentially uses [inverse reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242). It's just as quick *mentally* by Gauss's algorithm because $\,\color{#c00}{5\cdot 22\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, 27(22)\equiv (2+5\cdot\color{#c00}5)\color{#c00}{22}\equiv 2\cdot\color{#c00}{22}+5\cdot\color{#c00}1\equiv 49\ \ \ $

Comment: Well, the real magic is that you are assuming that the expression $3x^2-x-9$ can be expressed as $(ax+b)^2$. Which a priori we don't know. We just got lucky that the problem was proposed in a way such that this is the case.

Comment: @Julian Testing if a (polynomial) is a square by the method of undetermined coefs is (standard) math, not magic.

Comment: I meant that it's magical that everything works out. Although it's actually not coincidence, it's clear that the question was made in that way by purpose. Because, I really don't think the problem is doable easily  if the right hand side is not a perfect square.